# Re-Targeting .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using .Net Framework 4.6.1 as Target Framework. And I tried to change that with using Properties. When I change the target 4.6.1 to 4.0 Visual Studio list errors. How can I change that with no error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Compare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\AccountViewModels.cs   99  Active
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Claims' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs   5   Active
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Claims' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs   5   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ClaimsIdentity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs   99  Active
Error   CS0508  'ApplicationSignInManager.CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser)': return type must be 'Task<ClaimsIdentity>' to match overridden member 'SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>.CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser)'    VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs   99  Active
Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'ClaimsIdentity' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found    VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs   99  Active
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Claims' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  4   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'EmailAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\AccountViewModels.cs   53  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'EmailAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\AccountViewModels.cs   68  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Compare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\AccountViewModels.cs   80  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ErrorMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\AccountViewModels.cs   80  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'EmailAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\AccountViewModels.cs   87  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ErrorMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\AccountViewModels.cs   99  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'EmailAddress' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\AccountViewModels.cs   108 Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\Basket.cs  10  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\Book.cs    10  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\Category.cs    10  Active
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Claims' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\IdentityModels.cs  2   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ClaimsIdentity' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\IdentityModels.cs  12  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Compare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\ManageViewModels.cs    38  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ErrorMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\ManageViewModels.cs    38  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Compare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\ManageViewModels.cs    57  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ErrorMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\ManageViewModels.cs    57  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Phone' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\ManageViewModels.cs    64  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Phone' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\ManageViewModels.cs    76  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\MovieDVD.cs    10  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\MusicCD.cs 10  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\Product.cs 10  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\SaleItem.cs    10  Active
Error       Some NuGet packages were installed using a target framework different from the current target framework and may need to be reinstalled. Visit http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages for more information.  Packages affected: EntityFramework, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, Microsoft.AspNet.Razor, Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Microsoft.Owin, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Microsoft.Owin.Security, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google, Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount, Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter, Newtonsoft.Json VeriPark001     0   
Error   CS0117  'Task' does not contain a definition for 'FromResult'   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs   22  Active
Error   CS0117  'Task' does not contain a definition for 'FromResult'   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs   31  Active
Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'ClaimsIdentity' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found    VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs 33  Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<SignInStatus>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<SignInStatus>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  78  Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<bool>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<bool>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  100 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<SignInStatus>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<SignInStatus>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  123 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<IdentityResult>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IdentityResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  155 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  158 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<IdentityResult>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IdentityResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  184 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  205 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  251 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<string>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  290 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<bool>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<bool>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  313 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ExternalLoginInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ExternalLoginInfo>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  325 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ExternalLoginInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ExternalLoginInfo>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  365 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<IdentityResult>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IdentityResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  371 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\AccountController.cs  377 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<string>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   70  Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<bool>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<bool>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   71  Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<IList<UserLoginInfo>>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IList<UserLoginInfo>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   72  Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<bool>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<bool>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   73  Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<IdentityResult>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IdentityResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   85  Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   88  Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<string>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   120 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   128 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<IdentityResult>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IdentityResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   139 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   140 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<IdentityResult>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IdentityResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   154 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   155 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<string>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   167 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<IdentityResult>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IdentityResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   182 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   185 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<IdentityResult>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IdentityResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   201 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   206 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<IdentityResult>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IdentityResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   231 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   234 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<IdentityResult>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IdentityResult>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   260 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   263 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ApplicationUser>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ApplicationUser>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   285 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<IList<UserLoginInfo>>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IList<UserLoginInfo>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   290 Active
Error   CS0019  Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int' VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   292 Active
Error   CS1061  'Task<ExternalLoginInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<ExternalLoginInfo>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Controllers\ManageController.cs   314 Active
Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'ClaimsIdentity' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found    VeriPark001 C:\Users\Pc-Oem\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\VeriPark001\VeriPark001\Models\IdentityModels.cs  15  Active
```

Comment: Well, if you use an _older_ .NET version then for sure you need to stop using _new_ features introduces in later versions (and. of course, dependencies targeting a newer version can't work)

Comment: Is there any way to do that? Or am i just stuck?

Comment: Of course there is. It may be a huge task or not, it depends on how many features you use aren't available (and how difficult is to replace them).

Comment: Most of the error messages above look like they come from asynchronous controller methods. You'd have to change them all in order to use the older 4.0 framework version. I wouldn't do that.

Comment: Based on the error messages, this project uses lots of async/await which means you should not attempt to downgrade to .NET Framework 4. 4.5 is probably the lowest.

Comment: I tried to downgrade to 4.5 and it work quite well i guess. And then I deploy it with FileZilla. I can see view but can't see datas. It shows me empty views.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I can bet you are using a Task entity in your model. Microsoft has System.Threading.Tasks.Task. If you want to avoid that error, just use "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" instead of simply "Task" where corresponds.

Hope that helps,